# Routing error using Inerita and Laravel on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, inertiajs

My app works on local environment, but after I deployed it on Heroku I get the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset')
```

and this is what is printed on the screen

[image: 1]

when I open the site

I've tried moving the script tag from **app.blade.php** after the *@inertia* tag and to add defer to the script, however none of these methods worked.

```
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @env ('local')
        <script src="http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js" defer></script>
    @endenv
</body>
```

Also I've tried following [this article](https://dev.to/rabeeaali/how-to-deploy-inertia-js-to-heroku-2cdn), but this didn't fixed it either.

I fell like I am missing something, any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey Alex, the script should be loaded in the head. The @ tags should be replaced by php/blade/inertia and is not a javascript issue. Are all the composer dependencies installed on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

```
stps to deoply laravel project on heroku server 

download cli 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

Prepare your Heroku CLI
Download and install Heroku installer base on your operating system.
heroku login

 Create Procfile inside your main Laravel project directory and push your project into Heroku and past the below code 
 web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/

run the following git commands 
git init
heroku create appname
git add .
git commit -m “Initial Commit”
git push heroku master
now try to open your laravel project you will find 500 error

Step 4 — Adding some configuration in Heroku base on .env file
read complete about them here 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
you can check the image as well
https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*1uv-JEb3CNByEwC68vWGtg.png


Step 5 — Database configuration
First, click “Resources” menu, then in the “Add-ons” side, click “Find more add-ons”. You’ll redirect into Heroku Add-ons page.In the Heroku Add-ons page, we click Heroku Postgres. and install it its complete free .

then  set database properties 
check the link below 
https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*9jLE08DL6gHyYTP89MuZtg.png
https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*eMqch3Bz2J6BLGhZ6Himmw.png
https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*u7gxP2fMnm3yScq1D0qlNQ.png

to update your project  
Ok, now we need to commit and push our config/database.php update into Heroku repository. Back into terminal and running this

git add .
git commit -m “Update database connection”
git push heroku master

Successful, now you are ready to running your Laravel App with Heroku. Hopefully this tutorial is useful and help you all guys :)

Thanks
```